# How can I use R to find the x value(s) of the intersection of 6th-degree polynomial and a tangent of known slope?

Tags: r, polynomials, derivative

I'm trying to determine at what x value a 6th-degree polynomial regression line shifts from slope of <1 to >1 by identifying the point at which its intersects with a tangent of slope = 1.

I currently have a data table (dt.temp) showing stream surface elevation and discharge (in cubic feet/second [cfs]) as downloaded from the USGS using their package dataRetrieval. Scatterplot (including regression line) and summary of data table linked below, where V1 is time in POSIXct, V2 is stream elevation (feet above sea level), and V3 is discharge (cfs). dt.temp is a simple three-column data table, where each columns V2 and V3 contain only numbers and each row represents a single instantaneous collection of data.

[Scatterplot of data in dt.temp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGvDx.jpg)

I have successfully found the derivative of the polynomial regression line, but have been unable to solve it for 1. Code below:

```
poly_degree <- 6
model.temp <- lm(dt.temp$V3 ~ poly(dt.temp$V2, degree = poly_degree, raw=TRUE))
mt.summary <- summary(model.temp)
p <- polynomial(mt.summary$coefficients[1:(poly_degree+1)])
p.derivative <- deriv(p)
```

Running object p.derivative returns:

```
399172400 - 10476900*x + 97757.09*x^2 - 342.0041*x^3 + 0.001394729*x^4 + 1766846000*x^5
```

I understand that the x value that I'm interested in is that which would cause p.derivative to equal 1, but I'm unable to solve the equation for any value but 0 in R.

Thanks a lot, y'all.

Comment: if `399172400 - 10476900x + 97757.09x^2 - 342.0041x^3 + 0.001394729x^4 + 1766846000*x^5  = 1`   Then `399172399 - 10476900x + 97757.09x^2 - 342.0041x^3 + 0.001394729x^4 + 1766846000*x^5  = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

If
`399172400 - 10476900x + 97757.09x^2 - 342.0041x^3 + 0.001394729x^4 + 1766846000*x^5  = 1`
Then
`399172399 - 10476900x + 97757.09x^2 - 342.0041x^3 + 0.001394729x^4 + 1766846000*x^5  = 0`.

```
f = function(x) { 399172399 - 10476900*x + 97757.09*x^2 - 
    342.0041*x^3 + 0.001394729*x^4 + 1766846000*x^5 }
options(digits=14)
uniroot(f, c(-1,0), tol=0.00000000001)
$root
[1] -0.74556803112872
$f.root
[1] 1.1920928955078e-07

deriv = function(x) { 399172400 - 10476900*x + 97757.09*x^2 
    - 342.0041*x^3 + 0.001394729*x^4 + 1766846000*x^5 }

deriv(-0.74556803112872)
[1] 1.0000097751617
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm having a hard time following it, though - I'd expect an x value of the regression line-slope 1 tangent to be in the 149-150 range (just eyeballing the scatterplot photographed), but I see no values in that range in the code that you uploaded. If I'm understanding your code, I think that the value -0.74556803112872 is what it identifies as the x value at that intersection. If you have time, would you help me understand?

Comment: Around 150 would be slope = 1 IF the x and y-axes were on the same scale. They are not.